# is the legendary super saiyan 3 in the Dragon Ball Heroes manga?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-heroes

AFAIK, in the Dragon Ball Heroes videogame appears the legendary super saiyan 3. Is this character in the Dragon Ball Heroes manga?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The character only appears in the *Dragon Ball Raging Blast 2* Game. In the *"Dragon Ball Heroes: Victory mission"* manga, Broly appears as an antagonist under the command of Genome, however in his **Super Saiyan 4** state.

Answer (score -1):

Broly SSJ3 does appear in the manga. He is a character controlled by Nimu, who uses SSJ3 Broly.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide some references to your answer, like a wiki page to clarify because you answer clashes with the accepted one.